# How to get redirect URL with QDesktopManager in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, oauth-2.0

I have a Qt app and am trying to implement OAuth2 support for google. So far I have the following:

```
class OAuth2Flow : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void handleRedirect(const QUrl& url) {
        // Check if the URL contains the redirect URI
        if (url.toString().startsWith("http://localhost:8000/login_callback")) {
            QString authorizationCode = url.queryItemValue("code");
        }
    }

public:
    explicit OAuth2Flow(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    void initiateAuthentication() {
        QUrlQuery authorization_url("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
        authorization_url.addQueryItem("client_id", "CLIENT_ID");
        authorization_url.addQueryItem("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8000/login_callback");
        authorization_url.addQueryItem("scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
        authorization_url.addQueryItem("response_type", "code");
        authorization_url.addQueryItem("access_type", "offline");

        QUrl url("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
        url.setQuery(authorization_url);

        const bool result = QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
        return result;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    OAuth2Flow oauthFlow;
    oauthFlow.initiateAuthentication();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This allows the user to sign into a google account in a new tab in their browser. They are then redirected to another URL. Everything works fine. I want to know how I can grab the URL they are redirected to?

The returned code is in a query in the redirected URL. I need the code as it serves as a access token. Does Qt provide a way to do this? Of course the other way is to create a temporary server when authenticating but I prefer to avoid that. Additionally, a production application surely would not use localhost but rather a proper domain. Surely there is a proper way to do this?

Comment: You can't. `openUrl()` just tells the OS to try to open the url, and eventually returns if a suitable application has been found (which doesn't mean that the application is *actually* able to open the path). You have absolutely no control nor knowledge of what happens after that, the application could even crash right after starting up and your program will never know it. The only way to get that is by using the QtWebEngine module and show the OAuth page in a QWebEngineView, then connect to the related signals, like `urlChanged`.